How to resend the request to the server when response is not Successfull?
I use the following method to send a request to the server and receive a response.
    Call<ArrayList<MyModel>> request = client.MyMethod(myParam);
    request.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<MyModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<MyModel>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<MyModel>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Do Somethings
        } else {
            if (response.code() == 500){
                // Attempt ++
                // if Attempt <= 3 Attempt again and send request to server
            }
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<MyModel>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            // Attempt ++
            // if Attempt <= 3 Attempt again and send request to server
        }
    });

I want the request to be sent again when the server response was not successful and the code 500 was received and this request should be repeated max 3 times.
